# Only navigator shows changes in Illustrator CC 2015

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, artboard

[image]

Pretty much you can see that this line won't show visual change. When i try to change the stroke it shows only in the navigator bar but o

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the "View Outline". You must have pressed the shortcut by accident.

To view all artwork as outlines, choose View > Outline or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> (Windows) or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> (macOS). Choose View > Preview to return to previewing artwork in color.